# how do you print table in knitr

Tags: r, knitr

I am trying to us knitr to print data frame in table format using `xtable`:

````
```{r xtable,fig.width=10, fig.height=8, message=FALSE, results = 'asis', echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, fig.cap='long caption', fig.scap='short',tidy=FALSE}

print(xtable(d),format="markdown")
```
````

This is the data frame `d`:

```
d <- structure(list(Hostname = structure(c(8L, 8L, 9L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("db01", "db02", "farm01", "farm02", 
"tom01", "tom02", "tom03", "web01", "web03"), class = "factor"), 
    Date = structure(c(6L, 10L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 4L
    ), .Label = c("10/5/2015 1:15", "10/5/2015 1:30", "10/5/2015 2:15", 
    "10/5/2015 4:30", "10/5/2015 8:30", "10/5/2015 8:45", "10/6/2015 8:15", 
    "10/6/2015 8:30", "9/11/2015 5:00", "9/11/2015 6:00"), class = "factor"), 
    Cpubusy = c(31L, 20L, 30L, 20L, 18L, 20L, 41L, 21L, 29L, 
    24L), UsedPercentMemory = c(99L, 98L, 95L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 
    99L, 98L, 63L, 99L)), .Names = c("Hostname", "Date", "Cpubusy", 
"UsedPercentMemory"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Any ideas what I am missing here?

Comment: I think what you were trying to attempt was `print(xtable(d), type = "markdown")`.  When you use the `format` argument, partial matching assigns it to the `format.args` argument.  If you had used the `type` argument instead, you would have been told in the error that `xtable` only supports HTML and LaTeX output.  Pierre's suggestion to use `knitr::kable` is a good alternative.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try `kable` from `knitr`. It will format the table nicely.

[image]

If you would like to use `xtable` try:

```
print(xtable(d), type="latex", comment=FALSE)
```

Comment: @Pierre Lafortune, I was able to make it work with this: print(xtable(t), type = "latex"), but I also get this message in the pdf file: % latex table generated in R 3.2.2 by xtable 1.7-4 package % Wed Oct 28 12:42:49 2015, how do you not show the message?

Comment: In the code header, try setting echo=F and warning=F

Comment: It is already set to False, I still the message in the document. {r xtable,fig.width=10, fig.height=8, message=FALSE, results = 'asis', echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, fig.cap='long caption', fig.scap='short',tidy=FALSE}

Comment: Try this `print(xtable(d), type="latex", comment=FALSE)`

Comment: use knitr kable like this: `table %>% knitr::kable("latex")`

Comment: or use with markdown for html output: `table %>% knitr::kable("markdown")`

Answer (score 6):

While Pierre’s solution works, this should ideally happen automatically. Luckily, you can use knitr hooks to make this work.

That is, given this code:

````
```{r}
d
```
````

We want knitr to automatically produce a nicely formatted table, without having to invoke a formatting function manually.

Here’s some code I’m using for that. You need to put this at the beginning of your knitr document, *or* in the code that’s compiling your document:

```
opts_chunk$set(render = function (object, ...) {
    if (pander_supported(object))
        pander(object, style = 'rmarkdown')
    else if (isS4(object))
        show(object)
    else
        print(object)
})
```

This uses `pander` and additionally requires a helper function, `pander_supported`:

```
library(pander)

pander_supported = function (object)
    UseMethod('pander_supported')

pander_supported.default = function (object)
    any(class(object) %in% sub('^pander\\.', '', methods('pander')))

pander.table = function (x, ...)
    pander(`rownames<-`(rbind(x), NULL), ...)
```

For nicer formatting, I also use these defaults:

```
panderOptions('table.split.table', Inf)
panderOptions('table.alignment.default',
              function (df) ifelse(sapply(df, is.numeric), 'right', 'left'))
panderOptions('table.alignment.rownames', 'left')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are rendering your knitr/rmarkdown report to HTML, you can use the function `rmarkdown::paged_table()`.

For example:

````
---
title: "My report"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
library(rmarkdown)

f <- function() {
  paged_table(mtcars)
}

f()
```
````

This .Rmd is knit into the following HTML:

[image]

Also, consider using the [gt package](https://gt.rstudio.com/) via `gt()`.

Comment: I believe this only works because `f` returns the result of `paged_table()`, and this then gets displayed in the knitted report when evaluated at the top level. Returning a different value (or doing just about anything) in `f` results gives an empty report instead.