# Displaying dataframes in R Markdown

Tags: r, markdown

I can't find a method to remove the hash marks and row numbers from dataframes outputted to a word document in R markdown.  I'd like to be able to present only the data without those features

Comment: Have you tried [xtable or kable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33396650/how-do-you-print-table-in-knitr)

Comment: I don't think `xtable` will produce output that can be rendered in Word.  But `kable` should work just fine (the difference being that `kable` produces markdown output, `xtable` does not)

Comment: @hopnoggin, if my answer is sufficient, it's standard courtesy on SO to mark it as accepted (green check mark next to the answer); if not, come back with more questions or comments. Regardless, please don't leave this question hanging.

Answer (score 2):

The [`knitr` website](http://yihui.name/knitr/) and specifically the page on [Chunk options](http://yihui.name/knitr/options/#chunk_options) suggests the use of a separate chunk (before your want to display a data.frame in this manner) to change the default for the chunk option `comment`, perhaps like this:

````
```{r global_options}
opts_chunk$set(comment = NA)     # default value is '##'
```
````

to disable the inserting of comment characters on output. Realize that this setting of the `comment` option is applicable to all chunks that *follow* this chunk; this chunk itself will not be affected by it.

This does give the textual representation of the data.frame (as if it were on the terminal), and not a more refined representation. I second @PierreLafortune's suggestion to look at `knitr::kable`.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `sjPlot` package and specifically the [view_df function](http://www.strengejacke.de/sjPlot/view_spss/)