# kable all tables in markdown report

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, kable

Using markdown reports with *knitr* I would like to avoid typing `kable()` for each table I want to output, it's repetitive and not intuitive for readers of the code chunks. I would like the `kable()` output to be the default. Is it possible ?

I tried to add `print.data.frame <- function(x){ print(knitr::kable(x))}` to the setup but it didn't change anything.

Instead of typing in my reports :

````
```{r}
kable(head(cars))
```
````

I would like to type :

````
```{r}
head(cars)
```
````

And have the same output.

My reports are html in case it matters.

Comment: `head()` is not the only function I'll use, I want any data.frame output to be printed as  if it was wrapped in a `kable()` call.

Comment: Maybe a possibility is to make a hook and include this hook as a global option.

Comment: I'm coding and knitting, I'm too lazy to type kable (or too sloppy not to forget some),  the kables call also add verbosity and cognitive load and are not known by people who know R but not knir, so I'd rather take them out of my chunks

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent you might be onto something! I found this : https://www.r-bloggers.com/automating-r-markdown-tables-with-hooks/

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper can this help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/33396940/10447055 ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use `output.html_document.df_print: kable`?

Comment: it works by using the `render` option in the setup chunk, e.g.  `knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, render=pander::pander)` but I'll try your proposal as well

Comment: I can't get this to work, I tried pasting it at the end of my YAML header and I got the standard data.frame output, maybe you can add it as a solution to the duplicate link @Ralf?

Comment: ok got it, instead of `output: html_document` : `output:`, new line 2 spaces, `html_document:` new line 4 spaces, `df_print: kable` . Works as well :)

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper That's good to know. Maybe you could write this solution as an answer.

Comment: @StephaneLaurent I did and Ralf did as well :). See duplicate link